# Cant purchase in app products with newly created sandbox account

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've created a new sandbox account to test in app purchases
and when the purchase dialog opens, i see "use existing account"
so I click that, but then

When the account was created it asked me to verify it, so i did.
When I entered the credentials of that account in the `purchase dialog`, it then said i needed to go to settings and change the password.
I change the password, and then it tells me it `cannot find my apple id` anymore.

This happened 3 times in a row, i expect it to happen again if i try again.

What is wrong? This didnt use to happen, and my old sandbox accounts work fine.
The new ones are the problem.

Comment: Looks like there is a problem creating new sandbox users on iTunesConnect. Many developers are complaining about the same problem on Apple developer forums. Supposedly, Apple are aware of the problem and are fixing it.

Comment: Do you know since when this problem is occurring ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605202/ios-in-app-purcahse-sandbox-testing-says-i-have-the-wrong-password

Comment: I was only aware of the problem at the beginning of January. It is now working for me. Mahal's link will take you to an answer of a similar question. Follow the instructions and hopefully it should work for you, too.