# iOS In App Purchase sandbox testing says I have the wrong password

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I created a Sandbox Tester account in itunesconnect and verified the email address through the email that I registered on the web.

After verification, I tried to purchase something in my app with the Sandbox Account and I was alerted to change my password; so I did.

Then I tried to purchase something in my app again with the new password and it says that the Apple ID / password is not recognized.

Am I doing something incorrect in this process?

Answer (score 2):

What you do is correct. The sandbox service is currently down, see also https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70418

**Update 13 January 2017**

Finally it's working, sort of. You have to make a fresh sandbox account, login in your app, accept that you have to change your password you entered a minute ago, and then it works. Don't try to use accounts you have made the past few days, these are currently unusable.